# Cmake generate "Absolute file path" for CodeBlock projects

Tags: opencv, cmake, codeblocks, filepath

I use Cmake to build my cpp + OpenCV projets because my professor want a multi-platform builder and he use microsoft visual studio. 
Everything works good until I updated my Cmake from version "2.6" to "2.8.*", which is now the default version on Ubuntu 12.04. 
When I use Cmake to generate ".cdp", in the column "Workspace" of CodeBlocks, it shows:

```
Sources
    /home/{My workspace}/epi.cpp`
```

instead of

```
Sources
    epi.cpp
```

It never happened for Cmake version "2.6". And it is not user-friendly

Here is my CmakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH $ENV{OPENCV_DIR})

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

PROJECT(TP2)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(epipolaires epi.cpp image.cpp image.h)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(epipolaires ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I tried to go back to Cmake 2.6 and it works well. So I think it is a Cmake problem more than a CodeBlocks Problem. Can you please tell me how to fix it on Cmake 2.8.7?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I use OpenCV 2.4.2 and Cmake 2.8.7. OpenCV .cmake files are in `/usr/local/share/OpenCV`

Comment: It sounds like this [CMake issue](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12110) which was resolved in 2.8.6  Are you definitely running 2.8.7?  Did you try running CMake from a fresh build folder?

Comment: Thanks Fraser. But It doesn't work for 2.8.7, neither for 2.8.9(the newest release) only for projects using OPENCV_LIBS. If I don't ask it in CMakeLists.txt to find OPENCV, it will correctly generate relative paths.

Comment: Interesting, had the same issue for compiling with Visual Studio. So it seems that it is due to FindOpenCV.cmake ??

Comment: is CMake 2.6 + FindPackage(OpenCV) working fine?

Comment: Yes. It finds OpenCV.cmake. I can compile with it.